# PHP decode base64 API Response to array

Tags: php, protocol-buffers

I've got a problem with an API of a partner company. They use protobuf in their API.
Now they've send me an code example in javascript and I tried to "translate" it to PHP.

I can communicate with the API via PHP but the response is base64 encoded and in the javascript code this repsonse gets translated to an array

```
const msg = VehicleListMessage.decode(Base64.toUint8Array(array));
```

How can I replicate this line of javascript code in PHP?

Thanks!

This is what I get when I base64_decode

```
string(856) "


AWS-SIM-102
           AWS-SIM-102
                      AWS-SIM-1022v6.0.0:EZ?rtsp://navya_user:navya_password@127.0.0.1:8550/CAMERA_INTERIOR:GZArtsp://navya_user:navya_password@127.0.0.1:8551/CAMERA_DOWN_FRONT:FZ@rtsp://navya_user:navya_password@
127.0.0.1:8552/CAMERA_DOWN_BACK@JNAV-APIRX


AWS-SIM-103
           AWS-SIM-103
                      AWS-SIM-1032v6.0.0:EZ?rtsp://navya_user:navya_password@127.0.0.1:8550/CAMERA_INTERIOR:GZArtsp://navya_user:navya_password@127.0.0.1:8551/CAMERA_DOWN_FRONT:FZ@rtsp://navya_user:navya_password@
127.0.0.1:8552/CAMERA_DOWN_BACK@JNAV-APIRX

v6.1.0.alpha1:EZ?rtsp://navya_user:navya_password@127.0.0.1:8550/CAMERA_INTERIOR:GZArtsp://navya_user:navya_password@127.0.0.1:8551/CAMERA_DOWN_FRONT:FZ@rtsp://navya_user:navya_password@127.0.0.1:8552/CAMERA_DOWN_BACK@
JNAV-APIRX"
```

This is what I get in JS:

```
{"messages":[{"id":"AWS-SIM-102","name":"AWS-SIM-102","tech_name":"AWS-SIM-102","manufacturer":"","model":"","soft_version":"v6.0.0","sensors":[{"camera":{"id":"INTERIOR","infos":"rtsp://navya_user:navya_password@127.0.0.1:8550/CAMERA_INTERIOR"}},{"camera":{"id":"DOWN_FRONT","infos":"rtsp://navya_user:navya_password@127.0.0.1:8551/CAMERA_DOWN_FRONT"}},{"camera":{"id":"DOWN_BACK","infos":"rtsp://navya_user:navya_password@127.0.0.1:8552/CAMERA_DOWN_BACK"}}],"type":"SHUTTLE","site_id":"NAV-API","streaming":{"type":"RTSP"},"online":"DISCONNECTED"},{"id":"AWS-SIM-103","name":"AWS-SIM-103","tech_name":"AWS-SIM-103","manufacturer":"","model":"","soft_version":"v6.0.0","sensors":[{"camera":{"id":"INTERIOR","infos":"rtsp://navya_user:navya_password@127.0.0.1:8550/CAMERA_INTERIOR"}},{"camera":{"id":"DOWN_FRONT","infos":"rtsp://navya_user:navya_password@127.0.0.1:8551/CAMERA_DOWN_FRONT"}},{"camera":{"id":"DOWN_BACK","infos":"rtsp://navya_user:navya_password@127.0.0.1:8552/CAMERA_DOWN_BACK"}}],"type":"SHUTTLE","site_id":"NAV-API","streaming":{"type":"RTSP"},"online":"DISCONNECTED"},{"id":"AWS-SIM-101","name":"AWS-SIM-101","tech_name":"AWS-SIM-101","manufacturer":"","model":"","soft_version":"v6.1.0.alpha1","sensors":[{"camera":{"id":"INTERIOR","infos":"rtsp://navya_user:navya_password@127.0.0.1:8550/CAMERA_INTERIOR"}},{"camera":{"id":"DOWN_FRONT","infos":"rtsp://navya_user:navya_password@127.0.0.1:8551/CAMERA_DOWN_FRONT"}},{"camera":{"id":"DOWN_BACK","infos":"rtsp://navya_user:navya_password@127.0.0.1:8552/CAMERA_DOWN_BACK"}}],"type":"SHUTTLE","site_id":"NAV-API","streaming":{"type":"RTSP"},"online":"DISCONNECTED"}]}
```

Comment: First do a `base64_decode()` and see what you get, show us, then we can see what else is necessary

Comment: I already did that and it returned a string (obviously). Ill send it here in a moment

Comment: I now edited my original post :)

Comment: Hmm  thats not very helpful! And what out of all that do you actually want to get

Comment: I added what I get in JS. I'll need something like this to work with it

Comment: Well thats a nice piece of JSON. Seems like something is missing here because Javascript is great but its not Magic

Comment: Is there a param you missed out on the call to get the data that would return JSON

Comment: @RiggsFolly no. The API just returns this base64 string that needs to be decoded. Protobufjs and javascript then use this string to make an array from it.

The Problem is: Protobuf for php is so complicated for me. For JS it seemed so simple to use...

Comment: Well it looks like you are going to have to get into it as this data is basically useless without it

Comment: @RiggsFolly thanks for your comments.. Maybe ill code it in JS and write what I need into my database and then use this in PHP...

Answer (score 0):

Assign the base64() value to a variable and then pass it through json_decode()

```
$str = base64_decode($response);  //$respone should contain the API response
$arr = (array)json_decode($str);  //this will array of the results from str!
```

Hope it works!

Comment: If you look at the data the OP is getting as a base64 decoded string, it quite obviosly will not respond well to a `json_decode()`

Comment: Yeah what RiggsFolly said is right. It is a string and so the json_decode just responses with an empty array :(